# windows 10 and visual studio 2017 boostrapper.exe problems

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2017

When I tried to install visual studio 2017 community edition right after clicking the file I got bootstrapper.exe couldn't load.

What is in addition to this I always get some lvt.exe error since 3 weeks when I start up the pc.

Now as I didn't find anything (and a bootrepair attempt in regards to windows didn't bring any difference): Can I somehow find out and repair whatever .dll is defective and thus prevents the bootstrapper.exe from being loaded?

P.S.: No visual-studio-2017 tag existing and I don't have enough points to create it.

Comment: which windows 10? VS2017 is not supported on Win10 Enterprise LTSB

Comment: @magicandre1981 windows 10 home

Comment: and which one? the original from 2015? run winver.exe, make a screenshot and post the screenshot here

Comment: @magicandre1981 Version 1607 if you mean that? (btw first time I heard that a windows sub version like enterprise and home makes a difference?

Comment: yes, 1607 looks ok. do you see any errors in eventlog?

Comment: Nope "Anwendungspopup: vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe - Anwendungsfehler: Die Anwendung konnte nicht korrekt gestartet werden (0xc00000e5). Klicken Sie auf "OK", um die Anwendung zu schließen. " is only an info  in the system part of the event logs but else nothing. (only info that the bootstrapper.exe couldn't start correctly)

Comment: 0xc00000e5 = STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR . so this is not helpful. [Run the VS log collector tool](http://aka.ms/vscollect) and report it in MS forums: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html and hope that MS can help you